# Switching themes with smarty template engine

Tags: html, css, smarty

I use Smarty as template engine and need it to switch between two color schemes. Basically all changes are in a few css files. All other files in the project are the same for all themes.

Smarty allows to set several template directories: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.template.dir.tpl so you can put all minor changes in first and use the second as a base, where smarty looks when it can't find a find in the first dirrectory.

But I need this mechanism for css, not tmpl files. How do I do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Config files](https://smarty-php.github.io/smarty/4.x/designers/config-files/) and [config_load function](https://smarty-php.github.io/smarty/4.x/designers/language-builtin-functions/language-function-config-load/)